# Listing files to array then covert them to pipe delimiter text files

Tags: arrays, sed, file-rename, tr, file-listing

I have couple of .dpff files. I want to do the following in Solaris 10 Sparc

1. Listen/wait for the director /cm/vic/digital/orcr/vic_export  for the arrival of one or more .dpff file. then
2. Remove the ^M character in all the .dpff files
3. add the file path to the first column of all .dpff files
   the file path is: /cm/vic/digital/orcr/vic_export
4. .dpff files are currenlty in tab delimited file so I want to then convert them to the pipe delimited file.
5. Lastly,  Rename each file with a time stamp eg. 20140415140648.txt

My code is below. I am not able the expected result.

Please advice.

```
#! /bin/bash

declare -a files
declare -a z

i=1
z=`ls *.dpff`
c=`ls *.dpff`|wc -l
echo "Start listening for the  .dpff files"
while :;
        do [ -f /cm/vic/digital/orcr/vic_export/*.dpff ]
        sleep 60;

echo " Assing array with list of .dpff files"
for i in c
    do
        dirs[i]=$z
    done

echo " Listing files"

for i in c
    do
        sed   's/^/\/cm\/vic\/digital\/orcr\/\vic_export\//' $files[i] > `date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`.dpfff
        tr '\t' '|' < $files[i] > t.txt

    done
done
```

Comment: don't use backticks, they're [deprecated syntax](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete).  Use `$(...)` instead of `\`...\``

Comment: What version of bash do you have?

Answer (score 3):

Hard to be sure what you're really asking: your description and your code don't really match up. Nevertheless, how's this?

```
#! /bin/bash

declare -a files files_with_timestamp

echo "Start listening for the  .dpff files"
while :; do

    # Listen/wait for the director /cm/vic/digital/orcr/vic_export for the
    # arrival of one or more .dpff file 
    while :; do
        files=( /cm/vic/digital/orcr/vic_export/*.dpff )
        (( ${#files[@]} > 0 )) && break
        sleep 60;
    done

    timestamp=$( date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S" )
    for file in "${files[@]}"; do
        sed -i '
            # Remove the ^M character in all the .dpff files  
            s/\r//g

            # add the file path to the first column of all .dpff files 
            s@^@/cm/vic/digital/orcr/vic_export/@

            # .dpff files are currenlty in tab delimited file so I want to then
            # convert them to the pipe delimited file.
            s/\t/|/g
        ' "$file"
        newfile="${file%.dpff}.$timestamp.dpff"
        mv "$file" "$newfile"
        files_with_timestamp+=( "$newfile" )
    done

    echo ".dpff files converted:"
    printf "%s\n" "${files_with_timestamp[@]}"
done
```